# How to make preConditions for two columns in liquibase?

Tags: sql, migration, liquibase

I don't know how to check two columns in table migration.
I use liquibase.
I wanna to make something like this:

```
        "preConditions": [
      {
        "onFail": "MARK_RAN",
        "not": {
          "columnExists": {
            "columnName": "first_column",
            "tableName": "my_table"
          },
          "columnExists": {
            "columnName": "second_column",
            "tableName": "my_table"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**not** is supposed to be an array of objects.
It may add additional logic by using  an “and” (default value) or “or” operators.

I’d go with the following:

```
 "preConditions": [{
    "onFail": "MARK_RAN",
    "not": [{
        "and": [{
            "columnExists": {
                "columnName": "first_column",
                "tableName": "my_table"
            }
        }, {
            "columnExists": {
                "columnName": "second_column",
                "tableName": "my_table"
            }
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Do I have to use "and" inside "not"? Can't I just replace the contents of the "not" block with contents of the "and" block (I'm talking about blocks in your example)?

Comment: No, you don't have to use "and" inside "not". Yes, you can replace the contents of "not" with contents of "and". You can build any logic you need.